# SPI: Receiving sets of bytes from master

Tags: spi, atsamc21

I have SamC21 XPRO board as a SPI slave with program written using ASF and Arduino Uno as a dummy SPI master. I expect 3 bytes long values.

The master sets `SS` to `LOW` then sends three bytes and then sets `SS` back to `HIGH` then waits a while and repeats it forever. I also had to add small delays between setting signals otherwise the slave had problems with receiving.

The code of slave checks if a value is received in a loop. It uses `spi_read_buffer_wait` funtion for checking. But the problem is that it receives any three bytes long value, not just the one between edges `SS LOW` and `SS HIGH`. So when the slave misses a byte then it starts receiving nonsence. Is it possible to receive a multi-byte value defined by `SS` signal and discard buffer content when the value is not complete (or receive shorter value)? Otherwise it is like random number generator.

I also noticed when I change code to receive only two bytes then it works faster and delays are not necessary. Could it be related?

I am new to microcontrollers so the code is made from [Example project](https://asf.microchip.com/docs/3.49.1/samc21/html/asfdoc_sam0_sercom_spi_slave_basic_use.html). Code of slave is:

```c
#include <asf.h>

/* SPI MUX define */

#define SPI_BUF_LENGTH 3
struct spi_module spi_slave_instance;

static uint8_t buffer_rx[SPI_BUF_LENGTH] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00};

void configure_spi_slave(void)
{
    struct spi_config config_spi_slave;
    /* Configure, initialize and enable SERCOM SPI module */
    spi_get_config_defaults(&config_spi_slave);
    config_spi_slave.mode = SPI_MODE_SLAVE;
    config_spi_slave.mode_specific.slave.preload_enable = true;
    config_spi_slave.mode_specific.slave.frame_format = SPI_FRAME_FORMAT_SPI_FRAME;
    config_spi_slave.mux_setting = CONF_SLAVE_MUX_SETTING;

    config_spi_slave.pinmux_pad0 = CONF_SLAVE_PINMUX_PAD0;
    config_spi_slave.pinmux_pad1 = CONF_SLAVE_PINMUX_PAD1;
    config_spi_slave.pinmux_pad2 = CONF_SLAVE_PINMUX_PAD2;
    config_spi_slave.pinmux_pad3 = CONF_SLAVE_PINMUX_PAD3;

    spi_init(&spi_slave_instance, CONF_SLAVE_SPI_MODULE, &config_spi_slave);

    spi_enable(&spi_slave_instance);
}

static bool spi_read_data(uint8_t *buffer_rx) {
    return spi_read_buffer_wait(&spi_slave_instance, buffer_rx, SPI_BUF_LENGTH, 0x00) == STATUS_OK;
}

int main (void)
{
    system_init();
    configure_spi_slave();

    for (i = 0; i < SPI_BUF_LENGTH; ++i) {
        buffer_rx[i] = 0x00;
    }

    while (1) {
        if (spi_read_data(buffer_rx)) {
            /* Data Output here and clear buffer_rx again*/
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. The slave must obviously check the SS pin to determine which group of three bytes belong to the same packet. Yes, the other problem could be related.

Comment: @Justme Thank you. I had problems with interrupts handling when using ASF. Finally I solved it, so now I don't use polling, but I use callbacks (ASF drivers handles interrupts). And the problem with receiving fast only 2 bytes long message is most probably problem of inefficient ASF driver.